# How do you install dependencies listed in Luarocks?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I have the following luarocks:

```
package = "project-name"
version = "1.0-1"
source = {
   url = "..."
}
description = {
   summary = "etc"
   detailed = [[]],
   homepage = ""
}
dependencies = {
   "lua >= 5.1, < 5.2",
   "busted >= 2.0.rc12",
   "lua-requests >= 1.1",
   "json-lua >= 0.1",
   "lua-resty-dogstatsd >= 1.0.1"
}
build = {
    type = "builtin",
    modules = {
        ["project-name"] = "project/init.lua"
    }
}
```

How do I install the dependencies? Doing `luarocks install` says I'm missing arguments. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: `luarocks install` alone won't do anyhting. you have to provide a module name

Comment: @Piglet yes I've said that, and hence the question :P

Answer (score 7):

To install a single dependency manually, you can run

```
luarocks install <dep-name>
```

You can append an optional version such as

```
luarocks install lua-resty-jwt 0.1.11-0
```

To install all dependencies listed in the Rockspec file,

```
luarocks install --only-deps <rockspec_file>
```

From the manual of `luarocks install`:

> --only-deps         Installs only the dependencies of the rock.

Alternatively, you can simply run

```
luarocks make
```

which will also install missing dependencies for you. However, do note that it may not be what you want, depending on your needs:

> This command is useful as a tool for debugging rockspecs.
>           To install rocks, you'll normally want to use the "install" and
>           "build" commands. See the help on those for details.
>
> NB: Use `luarocks install` with the `--only-deps` flag if you want to install
>           only dependencies of the rockspec (see `luarocks help install`).

Answer (score 3):

`luarocks build` will install all dependencies listed in the rockspec. If you do `luarocks init project_name` first you'll get a local luarocks command that will install modules locally to the project.  Have only tested this on windows. I assume other platforms behave similarly

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the question is although you install with that rockspec, it doesn’t install rocks declared in dependencies. 
Firstly could you do following command to check if above dependencies exist?

Command: `luarocks list | grep [dependency_name]`

For Example: `luarocks list | grep json-lua`

(luarocks list list all the rocks be installed)

Answer (score -6):

OK what's wrong with

```
luarocks install busted
luarocks install lua-requests
luarocks install json-lua
luarocks install lua-resty-dogstatsd
```

Comment: When you use `npm` or `python` do you use `npm install package1 package2 package3` or `pip install package1 package2 package3` or do you keep a dependency file like `package.json` and `requirement.txt` and then just run an installation on all of them?

Comment: Why are you bringing python to a lua discussion?  If you're not getting the answer you want maybe it's because the question is poorly formed.  You asked how to install these dependencies with the "luarocks install" command-line and it was explained to you.

Comment: The whole point of dependency management is that I don't have to manually run `install package1 && install package2 && install package3` and rather have some kind of a configuration where dependencies are defined in it, and I just say `install` and it will install all those dependencies for me. Exactly how to say Node, Python, Java, Go, PHP and all other languages do this.

Comment: @Rick the question is not poorly formed. The OP is trying to understand how to install ALL dependencies listed in a file with a single command, without having to specify them by hand. And it seems luarocks doesn't support that (?). If that's true, I'm just like OP curious why not.